# iOS imageView size unstable

Tags: ios

[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageUrl];

```
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(160, 90);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
[cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, I try to restrict the imageView of a tableViewCell with a fixed size since the images downloaded different. I write the codes as here, a strange thing is that the image loaded well the first time, but changed to the original size while deselect the row. If I scroll down to view all the data and turn back to the top, the size will not changed while operate on the row. I want to know the reason...

Comment: Please show more relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

set `UIImageView`'s `clipToBounds` property value to `true`

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```